# Delete button is covered by custom cell

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

[image]

I have an issue in one of my projects. I have one tableview like in the picture. My issue is my custom cell background is overlapping the UITableView delete button. Could any one please help me to bring it to front.

1. I have used below code but some of the developers are saying that If we use that code Apple may be reject your app

   ```
   - (void)layoutSubviews
   {
       [super layoutSubviews];

       for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
           for (UIView *subview2 in subview.subviews) {
               //NSLog(@"confirm is %@",[subview2 class]);
               if ([NSStringFromClass([subview2 class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView"])
               {
                   // move delete confirmation view
                   [subview bringSubviewToFront:subview2];
               } else if ([NSStringFromClass([subview2 class]) isEqualToString:@"_UITableViewCellActionButton"])
               {
                   [subview bringSubviewToFront:subview2];
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. another issue is the below code is only working upto iOS 7 but not working in iOS 8.
3. If I set the `- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` method to YES I don't have issues but we don't want indent.

Any ideas could be very helpful.

Comment: Maybe you've added your subviews directly to the cell, instead of it's content view

Comment: I have added to the ContentView only and one more thing is this code is working in iOS 7 but not in iOS 8 . The code is     if ([NSStringFromClass([subview2 class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView"])
    {
        // move delete confirmation view
        [subview bringSubviewToFront:subview2];
    }

Comment: can you add all the uicomponents to one view and then add the view to contentview while editing=YES just  set the size of the view to contenview size but still this is not a perfect solution . i have just managed this problem in this way.

Comment: it could be a autoresizing problem also once check those with different autoresizing contraints.

Comment: apple may changed the class of cell content view at ios8, so your code does not work. so you must do not use apple's private class.

Comment: Not able  to find UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView in ios11.Any help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hierarchy of `UITableViewCell` subviews is different in iOS 7 and iOS 8, try my solution.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {

        // for iOS 8
        if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView"]) {
            [self bringSubviewToFront:subview];
            return;
        }



        // for iOS 7
        for (UIView *subview2 in subview.subviews) {
            if ([NSStringFromClass([subview2 class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView"]) {
                [subview bringSubviewToFront:subview2];
                return;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Lee Jeff I have tried your code it is working like charm Thank you so much.One last question I have searched a lot in the apple docs also . Could you please share the link from where you got it?

Comment: One final question is If I use  your code will apple accept my app or not?Please let me know

Comment: Hi @Tendulkar, please try this tool, it's awesome [link](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLEX). my app is on sale now, dont' worry about reviews.

Comment: Exactly my thought, and the best way to see which view is subview of which is to use the Xcode 6's `Live Rendering` feature to `Debug Views` at runtime

Comment: Thank you I have awarded 100 points as bounty. Thank you for your time dude

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a button into contentView, not to cell view directly

Comment: I have added to the contentView only. Check my above comment